# dotnet build error on linux: sh : warning : setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8) [/home/j/code/tictacgo/UI/UI.csproj]

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, locale

I am running Arch linux and when I run the `locale` command in my terminal, I get the following output:

```
~ ❯ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When I run `dotnet build .` in my project root directory, I get the following:

```
~/code/tictacgo main ❯ dotnet build .
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  /usr/bin/sh: line 1: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
  v19.1.0
  /usr/bin/sh: line 1: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
  
  > tictacgo-ui@1.0.0 tcss
  > npx tailwindcss -i ./Styles/main.css -o ./wwwroot/css/site.css --minify
  
sh : warning : setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8) [/home/j/code/tictacgo/UI/UI.csproj]
sh : warning : setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8) [/home/j/code/tictacgo/UI/UI.csproj]
  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
    npx update-browserslist-db@latest
    Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
  
  Rebuilding...
  
  Done in 300ms.
  UI -> /home/j/code/tictacgo/UI/bin/Debug/net7.0/UI.dll

Build succeeded.
```

Here is the output of `dotnet --info`:

```
~ ❯ dotnet --info                    
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.103
 Commit:    276c71d299

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     arch
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.103/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.3
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       0a2bda10e8

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.103 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/home/j/.dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Why does this warning happen and is there a way I can fix it without changing my locale? I am based in the UK, so want the `en_GB` locale.

The warning is:

> sh : warning : setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

Comment: What distro are you using? Can you also include the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: Added the output. I'm running arch.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, msbuild runs programs by [explicitly setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL`](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/d94a10914756d94ae44d7cbce9d42427ea595b24/src/Tasks/Exec.cs#L594):

```
commandLine.AppendTextUnquoted("export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; . ");
```

So, if you want to work around the error, you should generate the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, even if you don't use it otherwise.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/locale suggests you should add `en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.gen`

```
...
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
...
```

and then generate the locale:

```
# locale-gen
```